# 404 error on Google.GData.Spreadsheets

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-signin

I had Spreadsheet application which worked fine for past few month.
But its not working now (Throw 404 error).

Here is the code:

```
SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("appname");
service.setUserCredentials(userName, password);

// It worked fine, but now I got 404
string token = service.QueryClientLoginToken();
```

Appreciate your answers/feedbacks

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: When was the last time you tried anything with the service? Because on the site it says:

> Important: OAuth 1.0 is no longer supported and will be disabled on May 5, 2015. If your application uses OAuth 1.0, you must migrate to OAuth 2.0 or your application will cease functioning.

Are you sure you have all the required steps performed to create a queryrequest towards the service?

Check out the gdata docs https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize

Comment: Thanks @brannmar: This piece of code worked fine until yesterday.I think OAuth 1.0 is no longer available. anyway thanks

Comment: No problem :) Always refer to the documentation if there is any :)